# Twitter windows phone 8 integration

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-8, hammock

Hello I am trying to run this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6 but I am getting an error.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Hammock.WindowsPhone.Mango.DLL but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with Twitter, you have to register your app at [Twitter Developer Site](https://dev.twitter.com). To do so, after you successfully logged in Twitter, you've to go to [My Application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps)s | Create a New Application. Now you have to fill the details of your app.

After getting those keys, go to Class1.cs and modify the **consumerKey** and the **consumerKeySecret**.

Comment: hello there thanks for your help, I have added these now i am getting this error in the message box : The given key was not present in the dictionary. Any help please?